# Variadic function (va_arg) doesn't work with float?

Tags: c, floating-point, variadic-functions

I have a variadic function which takes a float parameter. Why doesn't it work?

```
va_arg(arg, float)
```

Comment: Can you post the full function?

Comment: You're lucky that you were able to get an answer that is probably correct, given how little context you provided. Note that the answer is "textbook" ... that is, it's available to anyone who reads the appropriate documentation (e.g., man stdarg).

Comment: You are right the information is in the stdarg documentation. I didn't notice it before.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Parameters of functions that correspond to `...` are *promoted* before passing to your variadic function. `char` and `short` are promoted to `int`, `float` is promoted to `double`, etc.

> 6.5.2.2.7 The ellipsis notation in a function prototype declarator causes
>   argument type conversion to stop after the last declared parameter. The default argument
>   promotions are performed on trailing arguments.

The reason for this is that early versions of C did not have function prototypes; parameter types were declared at the function site but were not known at the call site. But different types are represented differently, and the representation of the passed argument must match the called function's expectation. So that char and short values could be passed to functions with int parameters, or float values could be passed to functions with double parameters, the compiler "promoted" the smaller types to be of the larger type. This behavior is still seen when the type of the parameter is not known at the call site -- namely, for variadic functions or functions declared without a prototype (e.g., `int foo();`).

Comment: I have a question regarding that, because I just had the same problem. I heard that `printf` also promotes `float` to `double`, but `printf` is  usually "working" ok for me. What is the difference between these two cases?

Comment: @Kusavil If you have a follow-up question, you would be better off posting a new question (you could reference this question in your post). Describe your problem, and show the problematic code. This would bring you more answers than just one, and it would have a higher potential of being helpful to others than a comment on an old question.

Comment: @ dasblinkenlight okay, I posted my own question :) Not sure if it's good question while my way of perceiving and understanding things here is lacking in many ways, but if someone would be interested, here's my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23836118/variadic-function-va-arg-doesnt-work-with-float-while-printf-does-what-the

Comment: @Kusavil Why, it's a good question, and you have four answers already! With the code in place it's much easier to understand what you're talking about.

Answer (score 11):

As @dasblinkenlight has mentioned, *float is promoted to double*. 
It works fine for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>          
#include <stdarg.h>

void foo(int n, ...)
{   
    va_list vl;
    va_start(vl, n);

    int c; 
    double val; 

    for(c = 0; c < n; c++) {
        val = va_arg(vl, double);
        printf("%f\n", val);
    }

    va_end(vl);
}


int main(void)
{
  foo(2, 3.3f, 4.4f);
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
3.300000
4.400000
```