# why float is promoted to double when using template and stdarg function

Tags: c++, templates

i made a template class Array : 
here is the necessary code :

```
#ifndef ARRAY_H
#define ARRAY_H
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdarg>

template< typename T >
class Array
{
public:
    Array(size_t length = 0, ...);
    ~Array();
private:
    T *m_values;
    size_t m_len;
};

template< typename T>
Array< T >::Array(size_t len, ...) : m_values(0), m_len(len)
{
    if(len != 0)
    {
        m_values = new T[len];
        va_list ap;
        va_start(ap, len);
        for(size_t i(0); i < len; i++)
            m_values[i] = va_arg(ap, T);
        va_end(ap);
    }
    else
        m_values = NULL;
}

template< typename T >
Array< T >::~Array()
{
    delete[] m_values;
}

#endif // ARRAY_H
```

and this is my main

```
int main()
{
    Array<float> a;
    return 0;
}
```

when i compile i get a warning "float is promoted to double when passed through (...)
so that means the problem source is the constructor that takes an unknown number of arguments.
why does the compiler promote the float to double, is there a way to solve it or i have to specialize the class for the float version, and how can i know if the compiler will also change other types ...

Comment: That's just how they work. Arguments passed into an ellipsis are specified as being promoted. Since this is C++, you can use a `std::initializer_list<float>` instead.

Comment: `...` requires all parameters to be on the stack.  My guess would be that your compiler passes a `float` value using the FPU instead, thus making `float` incompatible with `va_arg()`.  BTW, is there a reason why you don't want to use `std::vector`?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11270588/variadic-function-va-arg-doesnt-work-with-float

Comment: Passing through `...` *always* causes promotion from `float` to `double`.  Use a `initializer_list`.

Comment: Also, your Array class has very little utility, and it's made worse by using "...".  For example, try to create an `Array<std::string>`.  Instead, use `std::vector`

Comment: OT, but if you replace `T *m_values; size_t m_len;` with `std::vector<T> m_values` you will save yourself most of your development time (and probably get better performance)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a function with a variable-length argument list is called, the variable arguments are passed using C's old default argument promotions. These say that types `char` and `short` `int` are automatically promoted to `int`, and **type `float` is automatically promoted to `double`.**

Therefore, varargs functions must never receive arguments of type `char`, `short int`, or `float`.

Comment: Nice answer, but it looks a lot like https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx11c.html, which judging by the date in the footer predates this answer by a couple of decades.