# va_arg with other types return 0

Tags: c++, variadic-functions

I'm trying to write a generic vector class using the concepts of **templates** and **variadic arguments**. The essence of my Vector class declaration and its attributes look like this.

```cpp
template<unsigned size, typename T>
struct Vector {
    T data[size];
};
```

---

### Example

In the example provided below, I created 2 vector 3s, one of type `int` the other with type `float`. I then call a Set function (Implementation in following section), passing in the same parameters only differing in types. Results for the vector of type `int` is correct, but result for the vector of type `float` is not what I expected.

```cpp
Math::Vector<3, int> i_vec3;
i_vec3.Set(1, 0, 2);
std::cout << i_vec3 << '\n';

Math::Vector<3, float> f_vec3;
f_vec3.Set(1.0f, 0.0f, 2.0f);
std::cout << f_vec3 << '\n';
```

Outuput

```
1,0,2
1,0,0
```

Expected outuput

```
1,0,2
1,0,2
```

> Observation: When calling `va_arg(va_list ap, type)` with `int` as `type` the result is correct. But upon using other types such as `float`, 0 is just being returned.

---

### Implementation of Set

> Member method with variadic arguments.

```cpp
void Set(T v, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, v);

    data[0] = v;

    for (unsigned i = 1; i < size; ++i)
        data[i] = va_arg(args, T);

    va_end(args);
}
```

---

### Reproducible example

Here is a minimal version of the problem for testing.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdarg>

namespace Math {
    template<unsigned size, typename T>
    struct Vector {
        T data[size];

        void Set(T v, ...) {
            va_list args;
            va_start(args, v);

            data[0] = v;

            for (unsigned i = 1; i < size; ++i)
                data[i] = va_arg(args, T);

            va_end(args);
        }
    };

    template<unsigned size, typename T>
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Vector<size, T>& v) {
        os << v.data[0];
        for (unsigned i = 1; i < size; ++i)
            os << ',' << v.data[i];
        return os;
    }
}

int main() {
    Math::Vector<3, int> i_vec3;
    i_vec3.Set(1, 0, 2);
    std::cout << i_vec3 << '\n';

    Math::Vector<3, float> f_vec3;
    f_vec3.Set(1.0f, 0.0f, 2.0f);
    std::cout << f_vec3 << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

---

### Remarks

This is my first attempt at variadic arguments, so it will be great to know what misconceptions I may have that is causing this unexpected result.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. eg where is your `operator<<` ?

Comment: I have added a reproducible example. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have undefined behaviour, `va_arg` for floating points work only with `double`, not `float`. [More here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11270588/variadic-function-va-arg-doesnt-work-with-float)

As workaround you could add:

```
template<unsigned size, typename T>
struct Vector {
    T data[size];

    using Type = std::conditional_t<std::is_floating_point_v<T>,double,T>;
```

for checking if `T` is float, is so, use double.
And the call is:

```
        data[i] = va_arg(args, Type);
```

---

`,...` was fine in C, in C++ you should use variadic function template:

```
template<class ... Args>
void Set2(Args... args)
{
    int idx = 0;
    int fakeArray[] = { (data[idx++] = args,0)... };
    static_cast<void>(fakeArray);
}
```

---

Fixed version with static_assert on size of parameters pack:

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/778a3c34ebd53445)

Comment: Thank you for sharing the workaround as well as the tip on variadic function templates. I will keep those in mind in future implementations.

Comment: Hi, am I right to say that this part `(data[idx++] = args,0)...` is iterating through the arguments and 0 is the default value?

Comment: While I like your solution you should add a check that `idx` is not exceeding `size`.

Comment: @t.niese Thxs, I added modified version.

Comment: @JamesLim, yes all items in `fakeArray` are 0, comma operator `(e1,e2)` takes `e2` as initial value for all array's elements.

Comment: In C++17, you might even do `((data[idx++] = args), ...);`

Answer (score 1):

Your code has undefined behavior due to *default argument promotions*.

[Variadic arguments: Default conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments#Default_conversions):

> When a variadic function is called, after lvalue-to-rvalue, array-to-pointer, and function-to-pointer conversions, each argument that is a part of the variable argument list undergoes additional conversions known as default argument promotions:
>
> - `std::nullptr_t` is converted to `void*`
> - `float` arguments are converted to `double` as in floating-point promotion
> - `bool`, `char`, `short`, and unscoped enumerations are converted to int or wider integer types as in integer promotion

And your compiler will warn you about that:

> warning: passing an object that undergoes default argument promotion to 'va_start' has undefined behavior [-Wvarargs]

So what is happening in your code is that in `va_start(args, v);` and `va_arg(args, T)` you are referencing a `float`, but the variadic part is `double`.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation, it was very insightful.