# C : printf printing variables in the mixed order

Tags: c, printf, pthreads

Here is my code,

```
#include <time.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <unistd.h>

unsigned sleep(unsigned sec) ;

void get_time(char *buf) {  
    time_t t = time(NULL) ;
    struct tm tm = *localtime(&t) ;
    sprintf(buf,"%02d:%02d:%02d", tm.tm_hour, tm.tm_min, tm.tm_sec) ;
}

void *calculateSize(uint64_t size, char *buf) {   
    if (size < 1024ULL){
        sprintf(buf, "%.1f %s", (float) size, "B") ;
        return NULL ;
        }    
    else if (size < (1024 * 1024)) {
        sprintf(buf, "%.1f %s", (float) size/1024ULL, "KiB") ;
        return NULL ;
    } 
    else if (size > (1024 * 1024)) {
        sprintf(buf, "%.1f %s", (float) size/(1024ULL * 1024ULL), "MiB") ;
        return NULL ;
    } 
    strcpy(buf, "0") ;
    return NULL ; 
}

void * run(char *interface, char * download_buf, char * upload_buf) {
    unsigned long rdiff,tdiff ;
    unsigned long rx_old,rx_new ;
    unsigned long tx_old,tx_new ;
    char buf[10] ;
    char rx_file[512] ;
    char tx_file[512] ;
    sprintf(rx_file, "/sys/class/net/%s/statistics/rx_bytes", interface) ;
    sprintf(tx_file, "/sys/class/net/%s/statistics/tx_bytes", interface) ;
    
    FILE *rf = fopen(rx_file,"r") ;
    FILE *tf = fopen(tx_file,"r") ;
    
    if (rf != NULL && tf != NULL) {
        fscanf(rf,"%lu", &rx_old) ;
        fscanf(tf,"%lu", &tx_old) ;
        
        fclose(rf) ;
        fclose(tf) ;
    }
    else {
        return NULL ;   
    }
    
    sleep(1) ;
    
    rf = fopen(rx_file,"r") ;
    tf = fopen(tx_file,"r") ;
    
    if (rf != NULL && tf != NULL) { 
        fscanf(rf,"%lu", &rx_new) ;
        fscanf(tf,"%lu", &tx_new) ;
    
        rdiff = rx_new - rx_old ;
        tdiff = tx_new - tx_old ;                       
                
        fclose(rf) ;
        fclose(tf) ;
    }
        
    else {
        return NULL ;   
    }
    calculateSize(rdiff,buf) ;
    strcpy(download_buf,buf) ;
    calculateSize(tdiff,buf) ;
    strcpy(upload_buf,buf) ;
    return NULL ;
}

void *net_speed(void *thread_speed_args ) {
        char* iface = *(char **)thread_speed_args ;
        char carrier_file[512] ;
        sprintf(carrier_file,"/sys/class/net/%s/carrier", iface) ;
        printf("Reading from %s\n", carrier_file) ;
        while(1) {
                if( access( carrier_file, F_OK ) == 0 ) {
                    run(iface, ((char **)thread_speed_args)[1], ((char **)thread_speed_args)[2]) ;
                    } 
            else {
            sprintf(((char **)thread_speed_args)[1],"000 B") ;
            sprintf(((char **)thread_speed_args)[2],"000 B") ;
                sleep(1) ;
                    }
        }
        return NULL ;    
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char time_buf[10] ; //hh:mm:ss : 8 char + 1 null terminator char
    char download_buf[8],upload_buf[8] ;
    char* thread_speed_args[3] = { argv[1], download_buf, upload_buf } ;
    
    pthread_t thread_speed ;
    pthread_create(&thread_speed, NULL, net_speed, thread_speed_args) ;
    pthread_detach(thread_speed) ;
    
    while(1){
        get_time(time_buf) ;
        printf("Down:%s Up:%s %s\n", thread_speed_args[1], thread_speed_args[2], time_buf) ;
        fflush(stdout) ;
        sleep(1) ;
    }
}
```

I am using a thread to continuously monitor my wireless data transfer rate on an interface, I am also printing the time along with the transfer rate. I am just experimenting with threads, forgive me if my programming logic is bad.

I notice that when I do a speed test the output or print becomes all messed up like below

```
Down:0.0 B Up:0.0 B 23:49:03
Down:0.0 B Up:0.0 B 23:49:04
Down:0.0 B Up:0.0 B 23:49:05
Down:17.0 KiB9.2 KiB Up:9.2 KiB 23:49:06
Down:5.3 KiB Up:6.5 KiB 23:49:07
Down:3.4 KiB Up:4.1 KiB 23:49:08
Down:400.6 Ki20.3 KiB23:49:09 Up:20.3 KiB23:49:09 23:49:09
Down:918.6 Ki49.6 KiB23:49:10 Up:49.6 KiB23:49:10 23:49:10
Down:912.8 Ki53.5 KiB23:49:11 Up:53.5 KiB23:49:11 23:49:11
Down:959.2 Ki32.2 KiB23:49:12 Up:32.2 KiB23:49:12 23:49:12
Down:711.5 Ki33.8 KiB23:49:13 Up:33.8 KiB23:49:13 23:49:13
```

See the last few lines?

Could anyone tell me what is happening here? How do I correct it?

Comment: For a _variadic_ function `sprintf` do you need to cast with `(double)` or does the compiler extend this automatically when using `(float)`?

Comment: @CraigEstey Double would be `%lf`

Comment: Why do most of your function return `NULL`? Just make them `void`.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow I was on mobile when I asked that [somewhat rhetorically] where I couldn't double check. I've written a test case to be sure. With `(float)` calculation is done as `float` but, then, is converted to `double` for the call. With `(double)` calc is done as `double` [and the code is slightly smaller]. All _variadic_ `float` parameters must be converted to `double`. Because of that, `l` in `%lf` has no meaning for `printf` as all args are [converted to] `double`. For `scanf`, we need `%f` for `float` and `%lf` for `double` because we're passing pointers.

Comment: @CraigEstey I'm pretty sure that is part of the calling convention for your architecture and not specified in the C++ standard.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Um, no. It is default behavior on any arch. From a web search on: `variadic float parameters` we have ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11270588/variadic-function-va-arg-doesnt-work-with-float We're talking about C here, so C++ doesn't apply, but ... https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments

Comment: @CraigEstey I stand corrected. I thought only ints where promoted across all archs. But still nothing wrong with `%f` and `float`. The compiler will promote them and printf should narrow them back to float. It's just a bit wasteful to do all those conversions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While your threads lack any kind of synchonization (which will randomly garble your output in some rare cases) this isn't even your problem.

Here is your problem:

```
char download_buf[8],upload_buf[8] ;

char buf[10] ;
strcpy(download_buf,buf) ;
strcpy(upload_buf,buf) ;
```

You are copying an up to 9 character string into a 7 char string so that overflows the buffer. And since the buffers happen to be next to each other on the stack the second strcpy will overwrite the 0 terminator of the first string. Same with the time_buf overwriting the 0 terminator of the second string.

Overall a whole lot of undefined behavior due to buffer overflows.

Comment: Thank You!! I just realized this, increasing the buffer sizes seemed to make the problem go away. You talked about thread synchronization, could you tell me more about it in my case?

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you're accessing a common resource in multiple threads simultaneously - in this case, the STDOUT handle. You'll need to synchronize your threads when outputting the information to the console - the easiest way is using mutexes. You can read more [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mutex-lock-for-linux-thread-synchronization/).

Comment: Could you explain what STDOUT handle is? I only thee one thread accessing variables declared in the main function.
Would it have made any difference if I declared this variable outside main as global? Because in the past I wrote this code with all the variables outside the main and it did not have this problem

Comment: *The `printf` function is equivalent to `fprintf` with the argument `stdout` interposed before the arguments to `printf`.* Source: https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1570.pdf

Comment: That's not what is happening at all. The threads use sprintf and don't use STDOUT at all.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Check the last few lines and the while loop: OP is printing to STDOUT using printf and flushing the STDOUT. Accessing the same critical section (in this case, the while loop) from multiple threads must always be done with thread synchronisation.

Comment: Both the printf and the flush are in the main function. No other thread is accessing that while loop.

Comment: But that wasn't what causing the output I believe, as the answer below states it was clearly a buffer overflow which went away as soon as I increased the buffer array size